# Collecting Data from multiple IO-based Task from a single Thread-based task

Tags: c#, io, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

Using TPL, how do I collect results from multiple IO sources ("thread-less" tasks) and merge them into a sequence as they come in from their respective sources without spawning a thread based task per source to monitor them? Would it be safe to poll the sources from one thread?

```
while (true)
{
    try
    {
        IEnumerable<UdpClient> readyChannels = 
            from channel in channels
            where channel.Available > 0
            select channel;

        foreach( UdpClient channel in readyChannels)
        {
           var result = await channel.ReceiveAsync();
           //do something with result like post to dataflow block.
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw (e);
    }
    ...
```

How about something like that?

Comment: while loop is really needed in here? just curious

Comment: @Cuong Le - I want to continually poll and read my udp sources.

Comment: It's possible to do this kind of thing with `Task.WhenAny` or similar constructs, but I think a better match would be exposing an `IObservable` or `ISourceBlock` for each `UdpClient`. Rx or TPL Dataflow would be a better match for "pushed" events like this.

Comment: @Stephen C - IObservable/ISourceBlock spark threads. I need to collect data all from one thread not have multiple threads monitoring the different sources because there are a lot of sources.

Comment: This code above is executing in its own thread but each source should be monitored from that one thread and not create a new thread/per source. I'm trying to conserve threads.

Comment: @Eric: Both Rx and TPL Dataflow use short `Task`s on threads borrowed from the thread pool as necessary. They're not dedicated threads; there's no blocked thread if there's no current activity.

Comment: BTW, you should never use `throw e;`, because it resets the stack trace. If you want to rethrow an exception, use just `throw;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see several options here:

If you want fire up the calls to `ReceiveAsync()`, set them up to do something with the result (e.g. send to a dataflow block, like you said) and then forget about them, you could use `ContinueWith()`:

```
foreach (var channel in readyChannels)
{
   channel.ReceiveAsync().ContinueWith(task => 
   {
       var result = task.Result;
       //do something with result like post to dataflow block.
   }
}
```

One disadvantage of this is that you would need to handle exceptions in each continuation.

Probably a better approach is to use [`OrderByCompletion()`](http://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=TaskExtensions&referringTitle=Documentation) from Stephen Cleary's AsyncEx. This way, you can start all reads at once and process them as they complete:

```
var tasks = readyChannels.Select(c => c.ReceiveAsync()).OrderByCompletion();

foreach (var task in tasks)
{
   var result = await task;
   //do something with result like post to dataflow block.
}
```

Yet another option, useful for example if you want to limit parallelism, is to use `TransformBlock`:

```
var receiveBlock = new TransformBlock<UdpClient, UdpReceiveResult>(
    c => c.ReceiveAsync(),
    new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = degreeOfParallelism });
foreach (var channel in readyChannels)
    receiveBlock.Post(channel);
receiveBlock.Complete();

// set up processing here

await receiveBlock.Completion;
```

If you want to send the results to another block, then the processing mentioned in a comment above consists of simply linking them together:

```
receiveBlock.LinkTo(anotherBlock);
```

---

In all of the cases above, there is never a thread blocking to monitor anything. But the code to call `ReceiveAsync()` and then to process the result has to execute *somewhere*.

Comment: Is there a easy way to Remove UdpClients or stop them from receiving?